# How to handle a timestamp field where the off set is out of the acceptable bounds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a field in a data frame with is ISO time with offset:

```
pages[['dimension1', 'dimension3']].head()
               dimension1                     dimension3
  1572461291083.sanyrqy8   2019-10-30T14:45:42.71-04:00
```

Most of the rows are fine except some have an off set outside 24 hours.

```
x = pd.to_datetime(pages.dimension3)
```

> ValueError: offset must be a timedelta strictly between -timedelta(hours=24) and timedelta(hours=24).

Here's an example of a rogue data point that's causing this error:

```
2019-11-11T07:08:09.640-31:00
```

My current task is not to solve why the data exists in this way but simply to get the raw data into a Postgres.

Is there some kind of if else logic I can use on this field to tell pandas when using `to_datetime()` if the offset is larger than 24 then to change it to 24? This would alter the rogue example above to be `2019-11-11T07:08:09.640-24:00`

How could I do that with Pandas?

Comment: can you provide some more data, ideally you can pull these records by 
 using `pages.loc[pd.to_datetime(pages.dimension3,errors='coerce').isna(),'dimension3']` and change their values , or you can take help of `np.where()` , `np.where((pages.dimension3,errors='coerce').isna() , changed_time_values, pages.dimension3)`

Comment: Hi @anky_91, I tried your first code block suggestion and got:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py", line 1979, in objects_to_datetime64ns
    values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx", line 200, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:``` ...

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 208, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 778, in to_datetime
    values = convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/2.3/parser.html). It's great for parsing dates that give errors

```
import dateutil                                                                                                                                                                     

dateutil.parser.parse('2019-10-30T14:45:42.71-04:00')                                                                                                                               
# datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 30, 14, 45, 42, 710000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))

dateutil.parser.parse('2019-11-11T07:08:09.640-31:00')                                                                                                                              
# datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 11, 7, 8, 9, 640000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -111600))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you this seems to work however when subsequently trying to send the data frame to postgres I get an error 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py", line 1979, in objects_to_datetime64ns
    values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx", line 185, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
ValueError: Array must be all same time zone'
I'll post a separate question on that but if you have any pointers let me know